# Swipe catched by scroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a page view controller where the pages are aligned horizontally - so you will swipe to the side to switch between them. Each page includes a table view which is scrollable on the vertical axis (up down).

[image]

You can navigate the page view controller all over the screen - and the table view only within the table view area.

If you swipe left on the table view - the page switches as expected. 
If you try to swipe left, but it is recognised as a up/down - then the table view will start animating (default animation) and stops within a second or so. The problem is - you cannot swipe left/right to switch page while the animation is active. If you do - it will always recognise the swipe as an up/down and you have to wait until the animation finishes before swiping again.

Which options do I have to solve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by implementing gesture recognizer delegate method

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

To implement above method your viewcontroller class needs to implement UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.

You can simply conform to protocol like this

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

and don't forget to assign delegate class to your gestures i.e

```
someGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```